# Almost succeeding Moving Windows 7 to an SSD from Hard Disk without reinstalling

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot, ssd

I am trying to do so and I am almost able to do so.

This is how I did it

Install windows on the ssd. Then, if I reboot, the SSD suddenly becomes drive C

Run command prompt from windows installation. After that find the drive for SSD and the drive for old windows

Say the old windows drive is e and the drive for ssd is c

I do:

```
e:

xcopy *.* c: /c /h /e /s
```

That works perfectly with one small catch

I can reboot fine. Everything is running.

For some reason the ssd is now drive e and the old windows become drive c. I can go to windows explorer and see the e drive to be the system drive. Yap that's the ssd. Also, windows seems to still be using c:\users to grab stuffs. Because the c drives contain the old windows this sort of works out.

[image]

Well, I think the old windows settings must have been influential somehow.

I change the drive letter of the old windows to drive z and after that, possibly because windows cannot find c:\users, it won't boot anymore.

I think there is a small step I should do to ensure that the SSD remains drive c when I reboot through it.

What should I do?

I can change drive C to drive Z and drive E: to drive Z using computer management. However, doing so can't be done in one restart.

I think there should be a way via command prompt to ensure the next time I reboot this windows, the system drive, which is the SSD, is C:

Actually I think there is a file in windows that specify that the system drive is C:. For some reason that file is overridden on xcopy. What is the file? How do I make the system drive C again?

Is it in C:\Boot?

Comment: So whats the small catch?  There are easier ways to clone your installation onto a new system drive though.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are doing. But if you want your 'old' system on the SSD, why don't you just clone it to the SSD - e.g. with AOMEI Backupper ==> http://www.aomeitech.com/aomei-backupper.html

Comment: You see how the boot, system drive is the E drive? I want that to be the C drive